# WPF RichTextBox - Remove text formatting on paste and move caret properly

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am having trouble removing the formatting (bold, font, size etc.) on paste of some formatted text into a RichTextBox.

I have successfully been using the following:

1. Add a pasting handler to the RichTextBox

`DataObject.AddPastingHandler(RichTextBoxControl, TextBoxPasting);`

2. Remove formatting and insert text

```
private void TextBoxPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
   var pastingText = e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
   RichTextBoxControl.Document.ContentEnd.InsertTextInRun(pastingText);
   e.CancelCommand();
}
```

But unfortunately this always places the inserted text in the end of the RichTextBox. Also the caret is not moving.

Let us say you are at this positing:

`Helloꕯ World` and you are pasting  `Beautiful` you would get `Helloꕯ World Beutiful` instead of `Hello Beutifulꕯ World`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually inserting the text and cancelling the event you could just alter the text that is to be inserted in the `DataObjectPastingEventArgs`, and let the chains of the event do all the work for you.

```
private static void TextBoxPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
   e.DataObject = new DataObject(DataFormats.Text, e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string ?? string.Empty);
}
```

`e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text)` is getting you the plain text without any formatting. The caret will move properly since you are not canceling the events that were supposed to move it.